# Best way to create zip from files in AWS S3 in PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, zip

I sell songs hosted in S3. People select them and they can download, but if they buy the entire CD, they can download it as a zip file.
The problem is that i have to create the zip file on the fly, which is very slow.
I am using the Zip Library, adding files from string with file get contents and after that (which may take its time), the user client stars the download, which is a lot of time.
Is there another way to provide it faster, maybe with some other libraries?

Comment: Do you not have enough storage to store a zipped version of the album along with the unzipped?

Comment: this is an incredible solution, that solves the speed problems http://www.w2lessons.com/2012/01/fast-zipping-in-amazon-s3.html

Answer (score 5):

Create the zip file once, preferably when you put together the tracks, and upload it along with the individual tracks. No need to overcomplicate things.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some helpful links that may provide some insight as to how to do this better:

[Use php to zip large files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552516/use-php-to-zip-large-files)

[LAMP: How to create .Zip of large files for the user on the fly, without disk/CPU thrashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357073/on-the-fly-zipping-streaming-of-large-files-in-php-or-otherwise)